# Trying for amethyst but got something different. What is it?

Tags: dragonvale

I was trying to breed an amethyst dragon and I didn't get it but am curious to see what I got (also for anybody else wandering the same thing). It has 48hrs from breeding hail and sonic, in that order. Does anybody know dragon it is?

Answer (score 2):

For such cases, the [Breeding Sandbox](http://www.2084.org/dragonvale/breeding-sandbox/) is your friend.  In this case you've bred a [Sun](http://dragonvale.wikia.com/wiki/Sun_Dragon) or [Moon](http://dragonvale.wikia.com/wiki/Moon_Dragon) dragon.  You won't know till you can see the egg.

Comment: @Emily Since the answer helped you, don't forget to tick the checkmark so everyone can see this is answered your question - nice smiley :-)